# Mysql group by weekday, fill in missing weekdays

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with a MySQL query, that groups data in my table by weekday.

I need it to fill in weekdays that a missing in the data, for example sunday (weekday 7) in the SQL-example below.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc497d/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table test (
`id` INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`date` DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO test (`date`) VALUES 
('2016-05-16 00:00:00'),
('2016-05-17 00:00:00'),
('2016-05-18 00:00:00'),
('2016-05-20 00:00:00'),
('2016-05-21 00:00:00'),
('2016-05-22 00:00:00'),
('2016-05-16 00:00:00'),
('2016-05-17 00:00:00'),
('2016-05-18 00:00:00'),
('2016-05-20 00:00:00');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(date) AS weekday,
    COUNT(id) AS posts
FROM test
GROUP BY WEEKDAY(date)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc497d/2/0)**:

```
| weekday | posts |
|---------|-------|
|       0 |     2 |
|       1 |     2 |
|       2 |     2 |
|       4 |     2 |
|       5 |     1 |
|       6 |     1 |
```

I expect it return this line too.

```
|       3 |     0 |
```

My complete query i quite complex so i hope you find a quick solution for this.

Comment: You have no data for that day.  Hence, it doesn't return a row when there is no data to return..

Comment: I think you are missing something... If you get `weekday` **0**, you cannot get `weekday` **7** (at least not in this planet).

Comment: I Think You expect `Weekday = 3 Posts = 0` In the results.

Comment: @TedoG.ty, you are right, just edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal approach is a `left join`:

```
select wd.wd, count(t.id)
from (select 1 as wd union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 uion all
      select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7
     ) wd left join
     test t
     on wd.wd = weekday(t.date)
group by wd.wd
order by wd.wd;
```