# mysql select default value for date if no results

Tags: mysql

I have a payments table grouped by day

```
select
 day(created),
 sum(payments.amount) 
from payments
group by day(created)
```

output

```
day | amount
1   | 432
2   | 4567
5   | 345
6   | 2345
7   | 97
```

which is fine, but i'd like to put some `0` in the days which did not have payments.

expected output:

```
day | amount
1   | 432
2   | 4567
3   | 0
4   | 0
5   | 345
6   | 2345
7   | 97
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql group by weekday, fill in missing weekdays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403859/mysql-group-by-weekday-fill-in-missing-weekdays)

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8888404/1040225

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have all the dates in the `payments` table you can do:

```
select
    d,
    ifnull(sum(p.amount),0) sum_amount
from (
         select 1 as d
         union all 
         select 2
         union all 
         select 3
         union all 
         select 4
         union all 
         select 5
         union all 
         select 6
         union all 
         select 7
    ) d
    left join payments p 
    on day(p.created) = d.d
group by d
order by d
```

Sample here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb09d1/2

Comment: no, i don't have all the dates in the payments table, but i need to return them as though they do if they're empty

Comment: @BlairAnderson: based on your comment please see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have the data for certain days in your table, thus you can't ask the engine to return you that.
Simply can't, it basically knows nothing about the human's calendar :-)

So you have to either retrospectively generate stub records with zeroes for these days, or use the method @bernie suggested, this particular way, or materialized in permanent table holding days from 1 to 31.