# Fetch data from last week, even if no entry is present on few day

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch data from two tables `post`, `post_like`

I want the data such that if row entry is not present in `post_like` table `null/0` as result to be shown

currently row data is omitted if the data is not present for a particular day.

I have prepared sample data

```
CREATE TABLE post(post_id INT, user_id INT, post_type INT);
INSERT INTO post VALUES (1,1,1),(2,1,2),(3,1,2),(4,2,1),(5,2,3);

CREATE TABLE post_like(post_id INT, user_id INT, created_on DATE);
INSERT INTO post_like VALUES 
(1,4,"2020-02-10"),(2,4,"2020-02-10"),
(3,4,"2020-02-10"),(1,4,"2020-02-11"),
(2,4,"2020-02-11"),(3,4,"2020-02-11"),
(1,4,"2020-02-12"),(2,4,"2020-02-13"),
(3,4,"2020-02-13"),(1,4,"2020-02-14"),
(2,4,"2020-02-14"),(3,4,"2020-02-16"),
(1,4,"2020-02-16"),(2,4,"2020-02-16"),
(3,4,"2020-02-17"),(4,4,"2020-02-10"),
(5,4,"2020-02-16"),(4,4,"2020-02-10"),
(4,4,"2020-02-15"),(4,4,"2020-02-13"),
(5,4,"2020-02-11");
```

[`SQL fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e29069/1/0)

Query I am using

```
SELECT COUNT(a.post_id) AS likeCnt
     , DAYNAME(DATE(a.created_on)) as day
  FROM post_like a 
  JOIN post b 
    ON b.post_id = a.post_id 
 WHERE a.created_on BETWEEN subdate(curdate(),dayofweek(curdate())+5) AND 
 subdate(curdate(),dayofweek(curdate())-1) 
   AND b.user_id = 1 
   AND b.post_type = 2 
 GROUP 
    BY DATE(a.created_on)
```

above query returns me `day wise data` and `total count` of rows present in `post_like` table for that particular day but is `omitting result for a day if no entry is found`

I want to get the count for that day to be zero instead of skipping it.

**Desired Output Example**

```
likeCnt   |  day
------------------------
 4        |  Monday  
 2        |  Tueday
 1        |  Wednesday
 0        |  Thursday
 1        |  Friday
 1        |  Saturday
 0        |  Sunday
```

Comment: Edit your question to show us what the desired result should look like

Comment: How about adding the missing days in application language?

Comment: @Strawberry I updated my question with desired output, plz do have a look

Comment: @PaulSpiegel can you share few details / example ?

Comment: Initialize an array with all days with zero count. Then overwrite with what you get from the DB.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel can you share an query example? how can I modify the query to meet the requirement.

Comment: You don't need to change the query. What I'm telling is that you can solve that in the program code. But I don't know your program language.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel If it helps, there was a phpmyadmin tag there, before I deleted it, so that's a clue , I guess ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry - Not really.. It's just a standard admin tool. The app can still be written in node.js or what ever.

Comment: Server cannot return the data which is absent. You must generate the list of weekdays (or use static table with such data) and join your query source to it.

Comment: Here is a similar question: [mysql-group-by-weekday-fill-in-missing-weekdays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403859/mysql-group-by-weekday-fill-in-missing-weekdays)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(data.likeCnt, 0) likeCnt,
       day_names.day
FROM ( SELECT DAYNAME('2000-01-01') AS day UNION ALL -- generate daynames list
       SELECT DAYNAME('2000-01-02') UNION ALL
       SELECT DAYNAME('2000-01-03') UNION ALL
       SELECT DAYNAME('2000-01-04') UNION ALL
       SELECT DAYNAME('2000-01-05') UNION ALL
       SELECT DAYNAME('2000-01-06') UNION ALL
       SELECT DAYNAME('2000-01-07') ) day_names
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(a.post_id) AS likeCnt       -- and join the data
                 , ANY_VALUE(DAYNAME(DATE(a.created_on))) as day
            FROM post_like a 
            JOIN post b  ON b.post_id = a.post_id 
           WHERE a.created_on BETWEEN subdate(curdate(),dayofweek(curdate())+5) 
                                  AND subdate(curdate(),dayofweek(curdate())-1) 
             AND b.user_id = 1 
             AND b.post_type = 2 
           GROUP BY DATE(a.created_on) ) data  USING (day)
```

PS. ANY_VALUE() added for possible ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode.

Comment: prefixed date is used isn't there an alternative for it?

Comment: @VickySalunkhe Numbers from 1 to 7, for example... This is more an idea then the solution - it is not optimized.

Comment: i doubt is this will be more optimized with `SELECT 'Saturday' as day union all select 'Sunday' union all select 'Monday' union all select 'Tuesday' union all select 'Wednesday' union all select 'Thursday' union all select 'Friday';` 